# Mat radio button ripple effect animation fade out

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-8

I am using angular material 8 and I am using mat-radio button. I am able to ovveride the color of the radio button and the animation. But when I click the other radio button, the existing radio button fading out animation is still in pink color. I tried couple of classes to ovveride but not successful

```
::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple  {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #5d6469;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a workaround but you can try "background-color: #336699;!important".

Maybe a custom css class can solve this issue, as you will not need to use the "!important" and/or the ::ng-deep declaration